# Add body class based on existance of post thumbnail. Code works but receiving PHP Notice

Tags: post-thumbnails, debug

What I'm trying to do is add a body class based on whether there is a post thumbnail. The following works, but I get a PHP Notice. How can I fix the PHP Notice below?

```
function add_featured_image_body_class( $classes ) {

    if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $classes[] = 'has-featured-image';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_featured_image_body_class' );
```

PHP Notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-includes/post-template.php on line 30
```

This is the function in post-template.php

```
function get_the_ID() {
  global $post;
  return $post->ID; // this is line 30
}
```

**Update:**

Here's what I have now, which seems to work fine without PHP Notices

```
function add_featured_image_body_class( $classes ) {    
    global $post;

    if ( isset ( $post->ID ) && get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
      $classes[] = 'has-featured-image';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_featured_image_body_class' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function add_featured_image_body_class( $classes ) {    
global $post;
    if ( isset ( $post->ID ) && get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
          $classes[] = 'has-featured-image';
 }
          return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_featured_image_body_class' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That gives me `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 25` where line 25 is `if (get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {`. I also still have the original PHP notice and for some reason it's doubled.

Comment: @Andrew Where are you adding this code?

Comment: @RachelBaker NP :)

Comment: Hint: `isset ( $post->ID )`.

Comment: Ok I think it's a problem with my theme I'm developing, tried the code on another one I'm working on and it's fine. Will post back when I find what's wrong! thanks guys

Comment: Actually, as toscho pointed out, checking if it's set seemed to get rid of the PHP notice and everything seems to work now. I'll update my answer so you can see if I've done it correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I've edited your answer to include the `isset` and accepted it as the final answer.

Comment: The point is: a single global post object is only reliable available on singular views. So `is_singular()` could be used too.